# Objects or values as parameters for my service/data layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

I am designing this ASP.NET application as a 3 tiered system. Service Layer, Data Layer and User Interface. I am also using POCOS in the service layer properly mapped to my data schema. My Data layer follows the Repository pattern.

My question is: in my service layer / data layer should I be using my domain entities as parameters for my methods or should I just flatten all the properties. What is the best practice here:

this:

```
public void AddProduct(ProductDTO newProduct)
```

or:

```
public void AddProduct(string ProductName, int Category)
```

My impression is that the first one is better, the problem is that ObjectDataSource does not play well it it, is there any alternative to databind your objects that works the first approach, or will I have to go with manual binding.

Comment: What are you going to do when your object has 20 properties? Of course, use DTOs!

Comment: And How am I binding those DTOs to say a webform? ObjectDatasource does not support them, and manually binding 20 properties in the UI is a pain....

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ended up writing my own databinding framework and dropped objectdatasource alltogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely use a DTO. Otherwise every time you add or remove properties to products, you'll be adding and removing params from every calling, passing and called method.

With using a DTO, you only have to change/update the calling and the called method and think about the number of params you'd have to pass.

Comment: How am I binding those DTOs to a webform? Do I have to constantly bee using events on the code behind and manually binding them to the controls in the form?

Comment: What are you currently binding to? Couldn't you bind to that object and then use something like an auto mapper to map to the DTO?

Comment: So say I have an input form where I am inserting the product proeprties, name, category etc. So on button press add, i would have to:  Create an instance of the DTO, manually bind all the proeprties from my form to the DTO properties, and call the Service method using the DTO as parameter. If I use flat properties all I have to do is setup the objectdatasource and it does all this for me.

Comment: I did some research for you. Looks like you will have to set it manually. Found this link, it might be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ObjectDataSourceInDepth.aspx, which lists the limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I ended up writing my own databinding framework and dropped objectdatasource.